# if block between cy statements not considered while running tests with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have 2 fields to provide inputs. The second field gets enabled after 10 seconds from providing input to the first field. The default wait of cypress is not enough I think.
If I just say to wait for 10 seconds then it waits for each paper name. So, introduced a if block to wait for further 10 seconds so that the 2nd field gets enabled to provide input for this particular paper name.

The issue being faced is this if block is not considered while running the test. After setting the input for 1st field, wait is not addressed. Directly, it goes to 2nd field and test fails as it's not enabled yet.

```
let paperName = 'MathematicsFirstTermPL'
cy.get('app-screen').find(#master-code).type(paperName)
if(paperName.toLowerCase().includes('firsttermpl')){
cy.wait(10000);
}
cy.get('app-screen').find(#master-code).type('ALO19')
```

Instead of part of paper name, tried with full paper name. No luck with that. Any help on this?

Comment: Question does not make sense - you don't need if block, just add wait(10000). But it will wait either way because `'MathematicsFirstTermPL'.toLowerCase().includes('firsttermpl')` is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use `cy.clock()` and `cy.tick()` if you are not specifically testing for the second field becoming enabled after 10 seconds from inputting text into the first field.

A more long term approach would be to use [`cypress-recurse`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse) where you will input into the first field and after 10 seconds(if there is no other way to avoid hard waiting) check the second field.

```js
recurse(
    () => {
            cy.get('app-screen').find(#master-code).clear().type(paperName)
            cy.wait(10000) // wait 10 seconds
    },
    cy.get('app-screen').find(#master-code).should('not.be.disabled'),
    {
      log: true,
      limit: 5, // max number of iterations
      timeout: 30000, // time limit in ms for entire recurse
      delay: 300, // delay before next iteration, ms
    },
  ).type('ALO19') // yields the subject of the command function
```

Comment: I think you can drop `cy.wait(10000)` because `timeout: 30000, // time limit in ms` covers it.

Comment: The `timeout: 30000` is the timeout for the [entire recurse](https://youtu.be/Cn8Ubhd49Gw?t=153) (I'll update comment for it). It's another added protection to end the recurse besides the `limit: 5`.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. What about `delay: 10000` instead of `cy.wait(10000)`? Probably what I was thinking of.

Comment: The `delay` option works a bit differently. It's the time delay between iterations within the recurse, not a delay between commands.

Comment: Ok, understood. So, @saran needs the `cy.wait(10000)` to go between the `.type(paperName)` and the `.should('not.be.disabled')`, but increasing `delay` would put the wait after the `.should()`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and that is wha I have in my answer. The first argument is the action(s), the second is the predictive function that must return true to exit the recurse.

Comment: But if predicate returns false it repeats, so `.type(paperName)` occurs twice?

Comment: True, I forgot to add that to my answer. Updated now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should actually work, so something else is going on.

Try running `if()` block in beforeEach().

You may also need to requery the element after waiting (slow response, so DOM may be updated).

```js
let timeout = Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout')
let paperName = 'MathematicsFirstTermPL'

beforeEach(() => {
  if (paperName.toLowerCase().includes('firsttermpl')) {
    timeout = 10000;
  }
})

it('tests paper type', () => {
  cy.get('#master-code').type(paperName)
  cy.get('#second-field', { timeout: timeout }).should('not.be.disabled')
  cy.get('#second-field').type('ALO19')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the field is enabled after 10 seconds, you can apply a timeout of 10000 and a `should('be.enabled')` assertion. Avoid using `cy.wait()` as it will introduce flaky tests.

```js
cy.get('app-screen')
  .find('#master-code', {timeout: 10000})
  .should('be.enabled')
  .type('ALO19')
```